# На срабатывает запрос HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android

При загрузке приложения я создаю команду с HttpURLConnection, при переходе на эту страницу, если мы заходим с браузера он создаёт файл, но когда я загружаю приложение через телефон файл не создаётся, ошибок никаких нет. В чём может быть проблема и как решать данную ситуацию. Спасибо за участие!

```
package com.example.tel2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        // Создаём get запрос
        String request = "http://site.ru/pg.php?tel=123";
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(request);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        try {
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        try {
            connection.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы делаете запрос в сеть в основном потоке. Это прямо запрещено на уровне системы с API>14. Вам надо вынести запрос в сеть в другой поток. Иначе вы будете получать `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, который должны видеть в логах.

Comment: Попробуйте либу `OkHttp`. К ней ещё можно `Retrofit` добавить и `RxJava`